# Doxygen-style comments in vim for C++

Tags: vim, editor, comments, doxygen

I'd like to automate inserting comment snippets for C++ files. Google search suggested `c.vim` plugin. I installed it. Now when I create a file, I get template like following.

```
 /* =====================================================================================
  *
  *       Filename:  Foo.h
  *
  *    Description:  :
  *
  *        Version:  1.0
  *        Created:  04/14/2014 08:35:44 PM
  *       Revision:  none
  *       Compiler:  gcc
  *
  *         Author:  YOUR NAME (), 
  *   Organization:  
  *
  * =====================================================================================
  */
```

From `:h csupport` I catch I can create my own templates for comments. Is there simpler way  to get doxygen-style comments in project? Or maybe these templates are available somewhere?

Answer (score 9):

If you only need these comments and not the other features of c.vim, I'd recommend you to use some snippets plugin, such as [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [Ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips). Creating such snippets with these plugins is very easy and they are very powerful.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Doxygen plugin for vim. It's available [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=987). Simply enter :Dox to add your comments.

For example,

```
/**
 * @brief 
 *  
 * @param list 
 * @param size
 * @param key
 * @param rec
 *
 * @return 
 */
bool jw_search ( int *list, int size, int key, int& rec )
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) & [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) come with tunable project headers (the default is quite bad I have to admit). You'll have to override templates/c/internals/c-file-header.template to something like:

```
VimL: let s:filename = s:path_from_root(expand('%:p'))
VimL: let s:prj_dox_group = lh#option#get('my_prj_dox_group', lh#marker#txt('group'))
/**@file <+s:filename+>
 * @ingroup <+s:prj_dox_group+>
 * @author  <+Author()+>
 * <p>Licence:<p> Your Project Licence
 */
```

(All the other stuff is already taken care of: include guards will be added automatically in header files, and foo.h will be automatically included in foo.c(pp))

Then in a [local_vimrc-like plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc), you'll have to set:

```
" File: /root/path/of/the/project/_vimrc_local.vim
:let b:my_prj_dox_group = "gMain" " you can override it in subfolders
:let b:sources_root = '/root/path/of/the/project' " for mu-template
:let b:includes = [b:sources_root . '/**'] " I can't remember which ftplugin uses b:includes
:let b:included_paths = [b:sources_root] " for ftplugin/c/c_AddInclude.vim
:let g:alternateSearchPath = 'sfr:.' " (or equivalent) for a.vim and for foo.cpp to include foo.h
```

BTW, lh-cpp also comes with the [`:DOX`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/Doxygen.md#dox) command that'll parse a function signature to automatically generate its doxygen caption (@param[in/out/0], @return, @ingroup, @throw (`noexcept` and the deprecated exception specifications are analysed), ... will be filled as automagically as possible)

If we take Saraht's example, it becomes:

```
/**
 * «brief explanation».
 * «details»
 * @param[«in,»out] list  «list-explanations»
 * @param[in] size  «size-explanations»
 * @param[in] key  «key-explanations»
 * @param[«in,»out] rec  «rec-explanations»
 *
 * @return «bool»
 * «@throw »
 * @pre <tt>list != NULL</tt>«»
 */
bool jw_search ( int* list, int size, int key, int& rec )
```

NB: `«»` occurrences mark placeholders

PS: I have no idea how it will behave if your keep c.vim as I don't use it.